# HM-10/CC41 talk to BLE server

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, hm-10

I've done a lot of searching but have yet to find any examples of the data format for accessing a simple BLE characteristic.  I have a CC41 (HM-10 clone) that I have set to master mode and successfully connected to a BLE server device using a PC terminal program and the AT commands.  I now want to send the proper data to access a service such as Immediate Alert (0x1802) and it's Alert Level characteristic (0x2A06).  I know the full service and characteristic UUIDs and the data value for turning the alert on/off.  I can do so from the nRF phone app but it doesn't tell me the data protocol that is actually sent from the app.  I assume that the UUID needs to be sent as hex data, not a string, but nothing I've tried so far works.  If the phone app can do it, then I would think that I can do it manually as well.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to access the GATT characteristics from your PC, is that correct?

Comment: No, I am using my PC terminal program to send commands and data to a CC41 (HM-10) device which is connected by BLE to a server device.  I am trying to figure out the format of the GATT commands to send, similar to what my phone app (nRF) sends when it is connected to the server device.